# how to share behaviour between ractive components

Tags: ractivejs

Perhaps this is more of a basic javascript question than particular to Ractivejs.

How can I add shared behaviour to Ractive components... for example, if several components have a strip_whitspace() method, how can I avoid duplicating it in each component?

thanks in advance for any javascript or Ractivejs insight you can offer.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to do it is to use `extend`, which pretty much looks like how you'd inherit in traditional OOP. Under the hood, it uses prototypal inheritance.

```
var CommonClass = Ractive.extend({
  // define common stuff
  strip_whitspace : function(){...}
});

var FirstClass = CommonClass.extend({
  // FirstClass stuff
});

var SecondClass = CommonClass.extend({
  // SecondClass stuff
});
```

If you prefer a more compositional approach where you build the object on the fly rather than impose inheritance, you can always use an extend function from other libs, like lodash's `defaults`. I prefer this method because I can inherit from more than one common object.

```
var UtilsMixin = {
  strip_whitspace : function(){...}
};

var AnotherMixin = {...};

var FirstClass = Ractive.extend(_.defaults({
  // FirstClass stuff
}, UtilsMixin));

var SecondClass = Ractive.extend(_.defaults({
  // SecondClass stuff
}, UtilsMixin, AnotherMixin));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at *[Frequently Used Expressions](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions)* in RactiveJS. If you use a particular expression frequently, you can add that expression to Ractive's default data, like so:

```
var helpers = Ractive.defaults.data;

helpers.fromNow = function(timeString){
  return moment(timeString).fromNow()
}

helpers.formatTime = function(timeString){
  return moment(timeString).format("ddd, h:mmA");
}

helpers.humanizeTime = function(timeString){
  return moment.duration(timeString).humanize();
}
```